# How to get values from a table where value depends on another table?

Tags: database, oracle10g, database-connection

Hi everyone I'm using Oracle Database using Oracle 10g. I have 2 tables
Car and Owns.

```
Create Table Car(
"license" varchar(255) not null primary key,
"year" varchar(255),
"model" varchar(255)
);
```

I inserted these values

```
insert into Car values('12-3000', '2012', 'Axio');
insert into Car values('11-3000', '2008', 'Corolla');
insert into Car values('12-4000', '2013', 'Axio');
insert into Car values('12-5000', '2013', 'Premio');
insert into Car values('11-5000', '2010', 'Nano');
insert into Car values('11-6000', '2011', 'Alto');
insert into Car values('12-6000', '2015', 'Nano Twist');
```

This is Owns table

```
Create Table Owns (
"nid" varchar(20) not null,
"license" varchar(255),
primary key("nid", "license")
);
```

Also i inserted those values

```
insert into Owns values('123451', '11-3000');
insert into Owns values('123452', '12-4000');
insert into Owns values('123453', '12-5000');
insert into Owns values('123454', '11-5000');
insert into Owns values('123455', '11-6000');
insert into Owns values('123456', '12-6000');
insert into Owns values('123457', '12-3000');
```

Now I need to find the national id (nid) of those person who has "Axio" models.
How to write that query?
It may be this kind...

```
select "nid" from Owns where "license" = (select "license" from Car where "model" = 'Axio');
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

> select "nid" from Owns where "license" IN (select "license" from Car where "model" = 'Axio');

You can try using joins as well...

Comment: `select nid from Owns left join Car on Owns.license = Car.license where model = 'Axio';` - This one also works. Check the query speed and use  best one.